#  Equivalent of Java's BorderLayout

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, border-layout

Is there any? If not, what do you suggest? Right now we are using a plethora of split containers, and the way it's coded makes it very difficult to add new controls, especially in the same panels, resizing is hopeless amongst other things. It could be recoded again using split containers in a much better way, but is there a better alternative?

[image]

Image courtesy of Sun's "[A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)".

Comment: Try using the `Dock` and `Anchor` properties of `Winforms` controls to get this kind of layout.

Comment: Although offtopic, I would recommend switching to wpf, winforms are largely obsolete.

Comment: @Vlad I've been recommended WPF each time I ask a winforms question. Switching to WPF on a very very large project isn't an option at the moment :( Although I really want to...

Comment: @David: at least now you can make the right choice for the next project :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [`DockPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

Here's the demonstration image: [image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC21907.png))</sub>

which bears striking similarity to yours.

In WinForms, you just use the pre-existing [`Dock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) property (see also [`Anchor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)), as described here: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908

Comment: hm... isn't your link about a _WPF_ control?

Comment: @Gabe I'm looking for it in my Winforms project, can't find it >.< I think so, yes :(

Comment: @Gabe Found this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/ Looks good. Wouldn't have found it without your keyword "DockPanel" so I'm going to mark this as an answer :) thanks